# Relative path for axios url request requires a '/' prefix for local but not hosted server

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

Not sure if this is an axios issue or not, but this works for me locally:

```
axios('/api/test').then(response => console.log(response.data))
```

But on my hosted server, it requires this:

```
axios('api/test').then(response => console.log(response.data))
```

Notice that the url request prefix '/' is there for local and not for server.

Is there any way to handle this (maybe Laravel Mix?) without doing something like this hack:

```
var p = location.hostname === "localhost" || location.hostname === "127.0.0.1" ? '/' : ''
axios(p + 'api/test').then(response => console.log(response.data)
```

I'm using Laravel(5.8)/Vue with the standard folder structure. The request route above is:

```
Route::get('test', 'TestController@index');
```

and located in the AppName/routes/api.php file.

Comment: does the 2nd one work locally? why not just use it?

Comment: 2nd one does not work locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, but my final solution was to deploy on my host server the way I believe it was intended. I made the public folder a root folder and pointed the server to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe a flaw in the configuration of your Apache server (or nginx), but I suggest you use a configuration file to avoid problems like this:

```
// Define different API Url
const urlApiDev = 'urlApiDev'
const urlApiProd = 'urlApiProd'
const secretDev = 'secretDev'
const secretPROD = 'secretProd'

export default {
  url: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? urlApiDev : urlApiProd,
  version: 'api/1.0',
  clientId: '2',
  clientSecret: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? secretDev :secretPROD,
}
```

and import it where you need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a variable in your javascript file to add the path.

```
var host = window.location.origin;
axios(host + '/api/test').then(response => console.log(response.data);
```

Hope this works